# Compare columns and change one to match the other

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm looking to compare columns next to each other and then populate information.

[image] [image]

If computed is 100% or less, actual should match.
If computed is greater than 100%, actual should be 100%.

I have zero VBA experience and have no idea where to start.

I manually edit the column to the right (% actual complete) to match the column on the left (formula that calculates % complete from budget vs cost).

[image]

[image] [image]

Comment: Can't you just copy and paste?

Comment: without an example of the sheet it is hard to understand what exactly the problem is. One thing coming to my mind is limiting the column values strictly to 100% using another formula: ```=IF(C5>100%;100%)```. Is that an option?

Comment: Have you tried using the macro recorder to do it manually a few times and get some starter code?

Comment: @JMP no I can't just copy and paste but thanks

Comment: @Ultra Junkie I just uploaded some links of some pictures

Comment: @TylerH no I have not, didn't think about that option

Comment: I start to understand your problem. Can you also add a screenshot how the same columns should look after the macro did its magic work? I would be so bold saying that the rest should then be straight forward

Comment: @TylerH I would not waste time for the macro recorder. It produces no efficient code, and if there are thousands of line, constructiontechie still needs to loop through the sections.

Comment: @Ultra Junkie, I did a before and after screenshot for you, the idea is to make the right column equal to what the left column is saying. But.. if the left column is claiming more than 100, make the right column only go to 100%.

Comment: @UltraJunkie OP has *no* VBA experience. They are exactly the right candidate to start with the Macro recorder. I've written some fairly complex VBA off and on for the last 5 years and even I find it useful sometimes to just record a quick set of actions to remember what some property is called, etc. The point of it is not to produce efficient code but to help show someone how to do something. And for only a few thousand lines, efficiency isn't really a concern.

Comment: @TylerH I turned on the recorder and recorded myself changing the numbers but then what do I do?

Comment: @TylerH No offense.... I agree when it comes to things like conditional formatting because finding all the little details is cumbersome. But this is a straightforward looping through rows in a table which the recorder is unable to record the same way. And as he is new to VBA I was more thinking of giving him a proper starting point. Maybe if you could crosscheck my code I provided as answer and alter it where necessary that would help him get a grip on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just looking for a formula. No VBA required.  `=IF(A1<=100,A1,100)` should do the trick.

Comment: @ Brad Lee, I need a macro so that when I come into the sheet, I can click a hotkey that will look through the thousands of lines and do it automatically for me

Comment: @constructiontechie, put that formula in Cell H8 (or whatever cell is directly to the right of the data you have).  Then copy that formula into all the cells directly below that also require calculation.  The results will populate automatically when you enter new data.

Comment: What you gave me was perfect, finally had the time to sit and play around with it. Brad, is there a way to give this formula a "hotkey"? I want to be able to go in and hit Ctrl + B for example and it calculates using that formula you gave me.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  It will calculate as soon as you enter in the other numbers.  No need for a hot key.

Comment: I think that I will need a hotkey because as I'm scrolling through the columns I need to be able to press a button that will do it for me

Comment: You don't need the button.  Just put the formula in the cell you are trying to calculate.  It will calculate regardless of where you are in the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

After some thinking, maybe you might look for something like

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    
    i = 1
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheetname")

' Cell(i,6) is equal to row i, column F    
    Do While i <= ws.UsedRange.rows.count        ' you will have to define a criterium for the last row
        If Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 6)) And (ws.Cells(i, 6).Font.Bold = False) Then    ' no empty cells, no cells with bold
            
Debug.Print i
Debug.Print ws.Cells(i, 6)

            If ws.Cells(i, 6) < 100 Then
                ws.Cells(i, 7) = ws.Cells(i, 6)
            Else
                ws.Cells(i, 7) = 100
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop    
End Sub
```

It might not work immediately for you, but I hope it is a good start for making your own macro then working

Comment: Thank you, I feel like a darn idiot because I don't know what to do with this...

Comment: Don't! Each of us stood once in front of this new door asking how to get through. I saw that you took the solution with the formula which is great if it works for you. With my solution you can press ALT F11 which opens the coding window. Then add a new module (right click on the mouse) and copy the code into the window. With F8 you can walk through step by step. The next step is reading through an Excel VBA book or do research in forums like this (where I found countless life saving tips and tricks).

Comment: What do you mean in that code by I will have to define a criterium for the data on the last row?

Comment: The macro must find the last row somehow because looking for empty cells seems not a viable option according to what I take from your description. So if you put under the last row in cell Ax a string like "lastrow", this can be searched for. Or you enter the number of lines directly (which is less comfortable). If you can give me a clear criteria where to stop the search I can update the routine accordingly

Comment: I need the search to stop at the end of column J. It varies sheet by sheet, what we are doing is reviewing our month end numbers that come in for projects. Some jobs have more codes than others so there really is no way to have clear stopping point. One job could have thousands of lines to look through. One job could have 500 lines to look through... O

Comment: you can try to determine the last row with worksheet.usedrange,rows,count. However this method not always delivers the true last row, so be careful and check the result for your case.

Comment: This is what I am getting when I try to run that macro... I posted it to the top of the page. What do I need to fill in on this equation to make the macro compare columns F & G?

Comment: sorry for my late answer (and the commas instead of points). Busy days... if you want to compare using "usedrange", the code line must be ```do while  i <= ws.usedrange.rows.count```. For the comparison of F&G you simply use ```ws.cells(i,6) = ws.cells(i,7)```. I edited my solution accordingly.